# Unable to boot iOS Simulator 14 (all variants)

Tags: ios, simulator, xcode14

When attempting to use preview or to run my app on the iOS Simulator iPhone 14 (all variants) the simulator never boots and just stays in a booting/loading state while the preview for the same app never displays and just continues to show the activity indicator.

I tried reboot Xcode 14.2 and clear out the derived data folder.
I tried to run the app on the iPhone 13 Pro simulator.
I tried to reboot my Mac (Intel) with Monterey OS.

None of the above worked.

Answer (score 1):

For me just delete this folder was enough :

> ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches

Answer (score 0):

I found a link to a Medium article that solved my issue [here](https://medium.com/@liwp.stephen/my-solution-to-solve-unable-to-boot-the-ios-simulator-39bbb4aad100).

If the link fails, here are the key steps:

Delete all files in these folders:

1. ~/Library/Caches
2. ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches
3. ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport/
4. Also, for the above item, all subfolders except the simulator I wanted to use.
5. ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

The article also said to recreate the simulator if you delete them all but I did not need to do that.

After these steps everything worked perfectly (I did need to run the app on the simulator first before I could get Preview to work).